# Run Python project from shell

Tags: python, eclipse, shell, python-3.x, project

Eclipse can run a python project rather than just one `.py` file. Is it possible to run an entire project from Python 3.x shell. I looked into it a little, but I didn't really find a way. I tried just running the `.py` file with the main using `exec(open('bla/blah/projMain.py'))` like you would any python file. All of my modules (including the main) is in one package, but when I ran the main I got a `no module named 'blah' (the package it is in). Also, as a side note there is in fact an`**init**.py`and even a`**pycache**' directory.

Maybe I didn't structure it correctly with Eclipse (or rather maybe Eclipse didn't structure it properly), but Eclipse can run it, so how can I with a Python 3.4.1 shell? Do I have to put something in `__init__.py`, perhaps, and then run that file?

Comment: Which os is it? Ubuntu or OSX?

Comment: Right now OSX; but I could implement it in ubuntu or windows, as well.

Comment: How do you know it is Ubuntu? :) What if it was mint?

Comment: Just a guess. After all Ubuntu is a rather popular distro... It is probably more correct to just say 'Linux' :-)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your file looks like -- if you have an `if __name__ == "__main__": do_whatever()`, then an import will not `do_whatever()` because the name of the imported module will not be `"__main__"`. (It will be whatever the name of the module is).

However, if it is just a script without the conditional, you can just import the module and it will be run. Python needs to know where the module is though, so if it is not in your path, you will have to use relative imports, as documented [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Answer (score 0):

Based on current information, I would suggest you to run it this way in OSX

1) Bring up the `Terminal` app

2) cd to the location where `bla` lives

3) run `python bla/blah/projMain.py`

Show us stacktrace if the above failed.